# SnowFlake Procedure Unload/Load data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to creae a list of json object by processing the result set from a different query execution. The liast of json I want to persist to another table and copy the json to a stage so that later i can run the copy command and json data gets copied to the other table. How can I acheive this? Any thoughts.? The code is shared as screen shot in the image attached.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/locVV.png)

Comment: Does your use-case not support using something like OBJECT_AGGREGATE to directly read from source table(s) and put resulting JSON into target table. After this you can unload resulting json from target table to stage location.

Comment: My use case is to read data from a query (joining few tables) and the iterate through resultset to batch the rows in groups based on some condition. Once this is done , i want to persist the result to a table. JSON is not something mandatory for my use case, i just thought if i can build a json array from result set and if i cud persist it some how.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are only looking to persist/insert the resultset getting generated within your procedure then you can try to incorporate something like following in your code -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure stproc1(anyvar varchar)
RETURNS varchar not null
LANGUAGE javascript strict
AS 
$$                                  
var rowarr = [];
var rowobj = {};
// BUILDING A DUMMY ARRAY
rowobj['processid'] = 100;
rowobj['loc'] = 200; 
rowobj['item'] = 300;
rowarr.push(rowobj);
// ENSURE TO nullify object BEFORE ANOTHER PUSH
rowobj={};
rowobj['processid'] = 10;
rowobj['loc'] = 20; 
rowobj['item'] = 30;
rowarr.push(rowobj);
len = rowarr.length;
var querystr = "";
var ret_str = "";
//Iterate though ARRAY to INSERT into target TABLE
for (var x = 0; x < len; x++) {
querystr = "insert into item_j values (?)";
var statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:querystr, binds:[JSON.stringify(rowarr[x])] });
var rs = statement.execute();
}
return "BATCH";
$$
;
```

After executing above result will be stored in table ITEM_J that has only one column of type VARCHAR.

```
select * from item_j;
+-------+
| T_VAL |
|-------|
+-------+

call stproc1('a');
+---------+
| STPROC1 |
|---------|
| BATCH   |
+---------+

select * from item_j;
+----------------------------------------+
| T_VAL                                  |
|----------------------------------------|
| {"processid":100,"loc":200,"item":300} |
| {"processid":10,"loc":20,"item":30}    |
+----------------------------------------+
2 Row(s) produced.
```

Comment: In my requirement , I need to insert million of record 50M or even 100M. Individual inserts may not be a right fit or else i could have inserted even without building json object. I want to use copy command some how to insert the records.

Comment: Not exactly sure on what you are trying to do here - in your code its building an array iteratively that itself is not a best approach given 100m records besides array having limit of 16M, so not even sure how that will work out and perhaps you are right, you should actually insert without building json object given you have large volume in which case being iterative is going to be challenging from performance perspective.. Never-the-less post your exact issue, if you looking for something like copy and having issue figuring that, then share your exact source and target for the copy.

Comment: How I am planning to do is, I will fetch 100K at a time and iterate the result set and put a batch number to each row (multiple rows can belong to same batch based on some value in the row fetched). After this, I want to insert this 100k record that i prepared in a different table. After this, again I will fetch next 100K and repeat the same process. I was hoping if this 100K records i could publish without direct insert one by one rather if i could unload this prepared 100K on some stage and after all my ieration done, i can run copy which will load all 100M data.